# Account manager doesn't work for android 4.4.2

Tags: android, twitter, accountmanager

I have twitter integrated android application,  for the twitter app installed in device
     I am using account manager to get screen name account manager. I done my code for that.
     Code I done work up-to 4.2.2 android but , " doesent work for 4.4.2" .

```
     accountManager.getAuthToken(account,"com.twitter.android.oauth.token", null,getActivity(), new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>() {

            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
            @Override
            public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> arg0) {
                try 
                {
                     Bundle b = arg0.getResult();

                     if (b.containsKey(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT))
                     {
                         Intent intent = b.getParcelable(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT);
                         intent.setFlags(intent.getFlags() & ~Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                         startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

                         String token = b.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
                         user_screenName = b.getString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);

                         System.out.println( "token  -------------- "+token);
                         System.out.println("user_screenName --------------- " +user_screenName);

                     }
                   else if (b.containsKey(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN))
                     {
                         String token1 = b.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
                         userName1 = b.getString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);

                         System.out.println( "token  -------------- "+token1);
                         System.out.println("userName1 --------------- " +userName1);

                         System.out.println("===================== in else ");

                         twitterCheckMailExist(userName1);
                     }

                } catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, null);
```